# NodeJS & Express authentication middleware not functioning correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, authentication, saml

I am attempting to run the function `isUserAuthenticated` on every request to the server by requiring it in `app.js` and 'using' it as so: `app.use(authenticate.isUserAuthenticated)`.

I have an `/authenticate` callback route that is being POSTED to by our SAML Identity Provider which contains the information required to validate the user and the session.  This is what is inside my `authenticate.js` file:

```
module.exports = router;
module.exports.isUserAuthenticated = function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.cookies.subject);
  if (req.cookies.subject) {
      console.log(req.cookies.subject)
    return next();
    } res.redirect("LINK TO IDP FOR VERIFICATION, callback func. is then ran to get value of user and session");
}
```

As referenced, this authentication function is being required and used in `app.js`: `authenticate = require('./routes/authenticate')`, and `app.use(authenticate.isUserAuthenticated)`.

**The problem:** No matter what variation of the `if` statement to verify if the subject cookie is present in the request, the authentication check is not being fired and the redirect to the IDP authentication route is not being redirected too.  The `console.log` checks in the code above are returning:

`undefined`, and
`{}`.

Authentication was working on a single route when I was using the `isUserAuthenticated` function manually like this: `router.use('/', isUserAuthenticated, function(req, res, next) {...`, but I am trying to **use this function globally so I don't have to manually incorporate this middleware on each route.**

Any advice/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: can you rather try to simply use app.use(function(req,res,next){if(true) next() else res.redirect(...)}) expression and debug it? usually it should work without hassles

Comment: Do you mean to move the ```isUserAuthenticated``` function outside of the authenticate route and just have the function in the ```app.js``` with an ```app.use()```?

Comment: u got it. that's how u write a universal function check before it goes to different routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as suggested in comment,

you can move the `isUserAuthenticated` function to app.js. It'd look something like this

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.cookies.subject) {
    next();
    } 
else 
    res.redirect("LINK TO IDP FOR VERIFICATION, callback func. is then ran to get value of user and session");

})
```

This will process all the requests before they are forwarded to the routes later.

Answer (score 1):

A middleware needs to be set on router object if you are using express js

```
router.use(isUserAuthenticated)
```

Don't forget to put this on the top of your routes file.

See the difference between app level and router level middleware [here](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html)

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding correctly.  Would this be at my ```/authenticate``` route where the ```isUserAuthenticated``` function is being exported, alongside handling the authentication logic/POST? I tried putting ```router.use(isUserAuthenticated)``` at the top but am getting: ```ReferenceError: isUserAuthenticated is not defined```

Comment: Either write this function in the file which has the routes or export this function from some other file and import in routes file