# How to pass a middleware function for authentication from the main server module to a router file

Tags: javascript, authentication, router, middleware, module-export

Somewhat new, please bear with me. Trying to use **passport** to authenticate *only specific routes* in a website. The routes are in a separate file called `blog_a.js`. I have the following functions created in the main `server.js` file:

```
function checkAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()){
        return next()
    }
    res.redirect('/login')
}

function checkNotAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()){
        return res.redirect('/')
    }
    next()
}
```

However, I'm trying to pass the above functions into the `blog_a.js` module, so I can use them as middleware to protect the routes within that module.

I have tried to use `module.exports = {checkAuthenticated, checkNotAuthenticated}` at the bottom of the main 'server.js' file, and then use a `let server = require('../server.js')` line to import these functions to the module that contains the routes I want to protect.

However, the above `server` variable comes back as undefined, and I've tried several permutations / destructuring methods to try to import it. All to no avail, I keep getting the routes failing due to the "undefined" object--`Error: Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]`.

How can I set up the authentication in the `server.js` file but then pass its authentication functions to be used as middleware within an individual route file?

I looked at [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44932028/nodejs-express-authentication-middleware-not-functioning-correctly?rq=1), but it doesn't clearly explain how to get the middleware functions from one module--`server.js`--to another module--`blog_a.js`.

Answer (score 0):

I got the following response on Patreon from Kyle of Web Dev Simplified, and it worked like a charm!

"You should be able to just create another file that is called authMiddleware.js or something like that. Then in that file define and export the functions at the end (module.exports = { function1, function2 }). Now in the places you need those functions you should be able to import them like so (const { function1, function2 } = require('./authMiddleware'))."

So I followed Kyle's advice and created the following separate file `authMiddleware.js`:

```
function checkAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()){
        return next()
    }
    res.redirect('/login')
}

function checkNotAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()){
        return res.redirect('/')
    }
    next()
}

module.exports = { checkAuthenticated, checkNotAuthenticated }
```

... and then used the following require statements to get access to the functions:

-in main `server.js` --> `const {checkAuthenticated, checkNotAuthenticated} = require('./authMiddleware.js')`

-in router file `blog_a.js` --> `const {checkAuthenticated, checkNotAuthenticated} = require('../authMiddleware.js')`

Thanks!